# Another Proof of Euclid's Theorem (infinite number of primes)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, alternative-proof, semigroups

Here $\mathbb N = \{2,3,4,\dots\}$ with the binary operation of addition.

If $m \in \mathbb N$ we denote by $G_{\mathbb N} (m)$ the semigroup generated by $m$.

Definition: A number $p$ is said to be prime if for all $m \lt p$, $\;p \notin G_{\mathbb N} (m) $.

We denote the set of non-empty finite subsets of $\mathbb N$ by $\mathcal F (\mathbb N)$.

Let $\mathtt E$ be a function

$\quad \mathtt E: \mathbb N  \to \mathcal F (\mathbb N)$

satisfying the following:

$\quad \quad\quad\forall n \in \mathbb N$

$\tag 0   \mathtt E (2) = \{2\}$

$\tag 1  \text{ If } (\forall \text{ prime } p \lt n) \; n \notin G_{\mathbb N} (p) \text{ then } \mathtt E (n) = \{n\}$

$\tag 2 \text{ If } \, (\exists \text{ prime } p \lt n) \; n \in G_{\mathbb N} (p) \text{ then } \mathtt E (n) \text{ is the union of all such primes}$

$\tag 3 \mathtt E (n+1) \cap \mathtt E (n) = \emptyset$

We have the following result:

Theorem 1: There exist one and only one function $\mathtt E$ satisfying $\text{(0)}$ thru $\text{(2)}$; it will also satisfy $\text{(3)}$. Moreover, for every $n$, all the numbers in the set $\mathtt E (n)$ are prime (the prime 'factors').

> Question: Can the theorem be proved in this $(\mathbb N,+)$ setting?

If yes, we can continue.

Theorem 2: The set of all prime numbers is an infinite set.
Proof
If $a_1$ is any number, consider the 'next further out' number

$\tag 4 a_2 = \sum_{i=1}^{a_1+1}\, a_1 = \sum_{i=1}^{a_1}\,( a_1 + 1)$.

A simple argument using $\text{(3)}$ shows that $\mathtt E (a_1) \subsetneq \mathtt E (a_2)\;$  (c.f. Bill Dubuque's [remark](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/631999/432081)).

Employing recursion we get a sequence $a_1, a_2, a_3,\dots$ with a corresponding chain of strictly increasing sets

$\quad \mathtt E (a_1) \subsetneq \mathtt E (a_2) \subsetneq E (a_3) \dots$

So there are sets of prime numbers with more elements than any finite set.  $\blacksquare$

**My Work**

Please see

[Using the recursion theorem to implement the Sieve of Eratosthenes.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2998187/432081)

The proof of theorem 2 is along the lines found in the [proof given by Filip Saidak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid's_theorem#Saidak). Also, if we set $a_1$ to $1$ in theorem 2 we get the researched OEIS sequence [A007018](https://oeis.org/A007018/internal).

Note that the proof supplied by Filip Saidak has most likely been known for many years; see Bill Dubuque's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30133/432081) to the math.stackexchange.com question

*Is there an intuitionist (i.e., constructive) proof of the infinitude of primes?*

Comment: Note, multiplication (of positive integers) is recursive addition. That is, we define $a\cdot1$ to be $a$ and $a\cdot(n+1)$ to be $a\cdot n+a$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes I know. But I get excited when something that appears 'bound to multiplication' - the prime numbers - can get released into a more elementary framework.

Comment: Agreed. It's like discovering that gold isn't just valuable stuff that giltters, but can be dealt with profitably as heavy stuff that settles to the bottom.

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes, sieving for gold seems like fun!

Comment: The [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/30133/242) via $\,n(n\!+\!1)\,$ has more prime factors than $n$ for $\,n\ge 1$ is surely much older than Saidak's 2005 paper.  The generated sequence is [OEIS A007018](http://oeis.org/A007018). Note: [adding $1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3001685/242) yields Sylvestoer sequence $a_{n+1} = a_n^2 - a_n + 1 = $ [OEIS A000058.](http://oeis.org/A000058) See the OEIS notes for other connections.

Comment: There is no need to construct the *entire set* of prime factors of $n\!+\!1,\,$ i.e. $E(n\!+\!1)$. The proof works as long as we can prove that there *exists* a prime factor of $\,n\!+\!1 > 1\,$ (e.g. its least factor $>1).$ [In fact it suffices](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/631999/242) to construct any infinite sequence of *coprimes* $\,c_n > 1$ since that quickly yields an infinite sequence of distinct primes $p_n$  being any prime factor of $c_n$ (e.g. least factor $> 1).$ Why do you prefer to use $E(n)?\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque This is a minimalist approach. As I indicated, you can actually define a prime number to be the $n$ for which $\mathtt E:(n)$ is a singleton using a recursive sieve. So, you can show (2) is true with 'multiplicative blinders' where it is obvious considering the 'guts' of the recursive function. I am working on $ \mathtt E:$ and other 'stuff' since that is where I am led by my thoughts. Can't help myself!

Comment: @CopyPasteIt The least factor $> 1$ of $n$ is prime (i.e. irreducible) is already quite minimal.

Comment: @BillDubuque Minimalist in the sense that results can be obtained with the least amount of number theory - addition and simple logical arguments gets the job done. From my perspective, (2) is logically a nice 'mouthful'. Thanks for the links!

Comment: @CopyPasteIt Well one can unwind everything down to Peano arithmetic, but that won't be very arithmetically enlightening.  Why prefer assembly language over the beautiful higher-level language carefully crafted by number theorists over many centuries?

Answer (score 1):

It is valid, but seems to be fundamentally the same as the classical proof; both hinge upon the fact that $p_1\times p_2\times \cdots\times p_n+1$ is divisible by some prime not in $\{p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n\}$.

Comment: @Copy It is poor form to change the question in a way that invalidates existing answers.